# Changing the Key to the kops cluster doesn't let me ssh to master nodes from bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, kubernetes, kops

I am trying to rotate keys for my Kubernetes cluster that I created through kops. Here are the steps that I followed -

```
1. Deleted the ssh public key from kops

     kops delete secret --name mycluster sshpublickey admin 

2. Created a new keypair and named it id_new 

     ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

3. Created a new secret with the new public key in kops 

     kops create secret --name mycluster sshpublickey admin -i ~/.ssh/id_new.pub

4. Updated the cluster by doing a rolling update. 

     kops update cluster --yes 

     kops rolling-update cluster --name mycluster  --yes
```

Now I can ssh into the bastion host using the new private key that I created.

> ssh -i id_new admin@bastionHostDNS

But when I tried to loging to a master or a worker node from the bastion host I get a Permission denied (Public Key) error.

```
> admin@ip-172-20-0-32:~$ ssh admin@ip-172-20-59-125.us-east-2.compute.internal
> Enter passphrase for key '/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa':  
>Permission denied (publickey)
```

I didn't create a passphrase but it still asks me for one and When I don't enter anything I get Permission denied. Did I miss any step here? I have checked all the security groups and the bastion host can talk to the nodes.

Comment: Might be related to you issue, find [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1876) similar reported problem.

Comment: Finally figured out. I had use ssh -A admin@ip to get access to the nodes. Since the bastion host didn't have a private key.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be solved by @Anshul Tripathi with adding a private key on Bastion host and propagating appropriate public key to the target Node machine for SSH connection.Evaluated to answer for any further community research.